# If $F$ is a field, what does the notation $F(x)$ mean?

Tags: field-theory

If $F$ is a field, what does the notation $F(x)$ mean? I am trying to understand transcendence degree of field extension, and I am stuck in this notation.

More context: I am reading [this pdf](http://web.stanford.edu/~amwright/TranscDeg.pdf), and my problem is in the very first page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, both Ian and ihf are right, depending on what the $x$ is in $F(x)$. If $x$ is an indeterminate, then the smallest field containing both $F$ and $x$ is the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $F[x]$. If $\alpha$ is the root of a polynomial in $F[x]$, as is the case with $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ then $F(\alpha)$ will be the field $F[x]/(p(x))$ where $p(x)$ is the monic irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ with $p(\alpha)=0$.

It would be considered awkward notation to use $x$ to represent the second case(which is why I used $\alpha$ to suggest it is not an indeterminate.), but not technically wrong. It would be my guess that if you see $F(x)$ without any other qualifiers, they are assuming $x$ is an indeterminate.

Comment: Hi, if $x$ is an indeterminate, is the fraction field $F(x)$ the same as  "the field of rational functions"?

Comment: Yes, because rational functions are the fractions of the polynomial ring $F[x]$.

Comment: Thanks! I am reading the section "Modules; Finiteness conditions" on William Fulton`s book *Algebraic Curves*. He writes: *Suppose $K$ is a subfield of a field $L$. If $v_1,\cdots,v_n \in L$, we let $K(v_1,\cdots,v_n)$ to be the fraction field of $K[v_1,\cdots,v_n]$.* In this case is he implicitly saying that $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ are indeterminates, i.e. transcendental over $K$? I am confused about what difference does $v_i$ being indeterminates or not make in the definition of $K(v_1,\cdots,v_n)$.

Comment: $K(v_1,...,v_n)$ is ALWAYS the smallest field containing $K$ and all the $v_i's$(identified as a subfield of $L$. The actual structure of this subfield will depend on what the $v_i's$ are. If they are all algebraic, then $K(v_1,...,v_n)$ will have finite dimension as a VS over $K$ but if one is transcendental, this will be infinite. The paper you are reading is mainly concerned with this second case, but I believe the statements are  for any $v_i's$(algebraic or transcendental) unless specified.

Answer (score 4):

In the context of field extensions (as you mentioned in the question), $F(x)$ is the smallest possible field containing $F$ and $x$. For example, one can construct $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ by adjoining the numbers $a+b\sqrt{2}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ where $a,b$ are arbitrary rational numbers. Note that this does result in a field, because sums, products, and reciprocals of numbers of this form are again numbers of this form.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention transcendence degree, $F(x)$ is probably the field of rational functions in one variable, that is, the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $F[x]$.

Comment: So we can't both be right for the OP's context, but I'm not sure which one of us *is* right.

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing: whether the two definitions coincide. Let me give more context. I am reading this file: http://web.stanford.edu/~amwright/TranscDeg.pdf My problem is in page 1.

Comment: @monomorphic, it seems that pdf uses $F(x)$ like I did: $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ are indeterminates.

Comment: @Ihf Can I go ahead to read the file with your definition? :)

Comment: @monomorphic both of these answers are right. The field of rational functions is the smallest field containing both $F$ and the indeterminate $x$.

Comment: @MattSamuel are both these answers applicable in my context? Please see the pdf in my edited post.

Comment: @monomorphic yes. The notation is completely standard, it's just that Ian's answer presupposes that everything is sitting in a larger field. This is always true, it just may not be the way it's presented.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thanks! One question: what about the notation $F(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$? Does it mean the smallest field extension containing $F,x_1,\cdots,x_n$, equivalently the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $F[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$?

Comment: @Ian You're both right. They're the same thing.

Comment: @monomorphic For that to be true we need all of the indeterminates to be algebraically independent. I don't have time to read the whole article but the whole point is to talk about transcendental elements, and when they're algebraically independent it's isomorphic to the field of fractions.

Comment: @MattSamuel So when one uses the notation $F(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$, is it implicitly stated that all $x_i's$ are algebraically independent over $F$?

Comment: @monomorphic Sean's answer is good too. You should keep in mind that you always need to carefully inspect what you're reading because the author has every right to write $F(x)$ where $x$ is actually $\sqrt 2$, it's just not typical. Usually they would be algebraically independent transcendental elements unless otherwise specified.